# Material-UI Autcomplete component broken when querying server reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI and their autocomplete form. The Array below is what the state.dataSource value is after the component queried the server. Unfortunately it shows 0-2 items and rarely 4 or the 5 it's supposed to. It's like it renders with what it has on the moment and doesn't update when the state changes.

```
Array[5]
0:"Metallica - Nothing Else Matters [Official Music Video]"
1:"Metallica - One"
2:"Metallica - Enter Sandman [Official Music Video]"
3:"Enter Sandman - Metallica"
4:"Metallica - The Unforgiven (Video)"




queryServer = (param) => {
 if(param){
  axios.get("/api/youtube/"+param)
    .then( (response => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: response.data
      })
      console.log(this.state.dataSource);
    })
    )
};
}
render() {
return (
  <div>
        <AutoComplete
          hintText="Type anything"
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          onUpdateInput={this.queryServer}
        />
  </div>
```

I've tried adding it a key and it 'works' but it rerenders without the input text nor the dropdown, but at least is consistent.

http://translatesongs.co:8000/